# Can I export/dump the table schemas for a Google Cloud Sql database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Title says it all I want to export the table schemas for a Google Cloud Sql database? I see how to export the data, but I want the schema.

Comment: Assuming that the Cloud SQL you are using is MySQL ... can you not execute a MySQL query such as described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html

Comment: This was very helpful thank you

Comment: Hello @Kolban , can you add you comment as answer so it can be more visible and help other people with the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

When using Google Cloud SQL - MySQL flavor ... the underlying intent is that it simply "is" a MySQL instance.  The value that Google provides is that it is a managed instance.  This means that the toil of management, backup, availability and a whole host of other operational characteristics are removed.

If we agree with this notion, then all *usage* of the Cloud SQL instance behaves as though it were a self-hosted MySQL instance and hence all the tools and procedures that one would use with your own MySQL instance are applicable.

For example, here is a link to the MySQL documentation on getting information about databases and tables:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html

This is equally applicable to Google Cloud SQL as a local instance.  This story pervades into all the other aspects and literature.  If you search for recipes to work with MySQL on premises, the same story should be applicable to Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[mysqldump][1]` to save the info without the data:

```
mysqldump -u root -h <IP_ADDRESS> -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
```